# Do I always have access to my domain powers?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, powers, cleric

I am playing as a cleric of Fharlanghn in my first D&D campaign ever. We are using 3.5 rulings and only the handbook to get our feet wet. This gives me access to the luck and travel domains which look attractive based on other games I have played (frequent computer gamer).

The mechanical question I have is around domain powers (since domains have "domain powers" and then "domain spells"). I know that domain spells are brought into play through the allowed domain spell slot. Are domain powers just an ongoing ability that I have access to? For example, will I always have access to the reroll power granted by the luck domain as well as the freedom of movement power from the travel domain to utilize when needed? Or is there a prerequisite that I missed when reading?

Comment: I've trimmed out a small part of your background to keep it more concise, and removed the last bit: we don't do tips and tricks here, just solve specific questions which have specific answers.

Comment: Welcome to the site. A fine first question. Take the tour. Push the help buttons. Don't accept answers too fast. (Someone else's answer could be more helpful than the first answer.). Have fun, and thank you for helping strangers.

Comment: I appreciate the insight!

Comment: Note that the [cloistered cleric](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#clericVariantCloisteredCleric) *also* gets the Knowledge Domain, even if he or she worships a god that doesn’t usually grant it, on top of the two from his or her god. Also note that *Complete Champion* has “Devotion” feats that you can replace your Domains with if you like – Knowledge Devotion and Travel Devotion are both *very* good feats. Though you *are* correct that Luck Domain and Travel Domain are *very* nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Domain powers are always available for use

The cleric needn't do anything special while preparing spells to have access to his domain powers, and, unless the domain power says otherwise, it is always available for use. The cleric class description includes this information in the section [Deities, Domains, and Domain Spells](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/cleric.htm#deityDomainsandDomainSpells):

> The cleric gets the granted powers of both the domains selected.

Although the domain powers are always available, it's nonetheless possible to render them unavailable through use (e.g. the granted power of the [luck domain](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/clericDomains.htm#luckDomain)) or to exhaust them because of their automatic activation (e.g. the granted power of the [travel domain](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spellLists/clericDomains.htm#travelDomain)). [Further, if the domain power is a supernatural ability (usually) or a spell-like ability (almost always), the cleric must take a standard action to activate the domain power.](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm)